# How to solve for the integrand in a definite integral equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have this integral equation: $$A = \int_b^c{F(t)dt}$$
Where I know $A$, $b$ and $c$. Is it possible to solve $F(t)$, if so, how can I do it?

Comment: Is there any reason that you cannot take $F$ to be a constant function? If not, then simply define $F(t) = A / (c-b)$. This is assuming that you want _a_ possible $F$, not _the_ function $F$, which cannot be uniquely defined.

Comment: Yes, I also know that $F$ is not constant unfortunately, I dont know what it is tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible - see, you know the area and limits on $x$-axis. There are infinitely many such functions.

[image]

Comment: Oh yeah, I get it. Thanks.